# How not to mess up the cache when working on some long vectors in memory?

Tags: c++, c, performance, caching, optimization

**Premise**

I want to do some kind of computation involving `k` long vectors of data (each of length `n`), which I receive in main memory, and write some kind of result back to main memory. For simplicity suppose also that the computation is merely

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    v_out[i] = foo(v_1[i],v_2[i], ... ,v_k[i])
```

or perhaps

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    v_out[i] = bar_k(...bar_2(bar_1(v_1[i]),v_2[i]), ... ),v_k[i])
```

(this is not code, it's pseudocode.) `foo()` and `bar_i()` functions have no side-effects. `k` is constant (known at compile-time), `n` is known only right before this computation occurs (and it is *relatively big* - at least a few times larger than the entire L2 cache size and maybe more).

Suppose I am on an single thread on a single core of an x86_64 processor (Intel, or AMD, or what-have-you; the choice does matter, probably). Finally, suppose `foo()` (resp. `bar_i()`) is not an intensive computation, i.e. the time to read data from memory and write it back is significant or even dominant relative to the `n` (resp. `k`x`n`) invocations of `foo()` (resp. `bar_i()`).

**Question**

How do I arrange this computation, so as to avoid:

- The data from one input vector clearing out cached data for another vector.
- Input vector data clearing out cached output vector data.
- Intermediary results of `bar_j(...bar_1(v_1[i])...)` remaining in registers or L1 cache if there's enough capacity to hold them there until  the data for v_{j+1}[i] ... v_k[i] arrives and allows us to complete the computation. Same for L2.
- The L1 cache lines of the output vectors being cleared while we intend to continue working on elements in that cache line. Same for L2.
- Under-utilization of memory bandwidth.
- core idle time, to the extent possible.
- Write-read-write-read-write sequences on v_out (which might be very expensive if those writes need to be updated into main memory; the motivation here is that it might be tempting to read just one vector, update the output and repeat).

**Notes:**

- Any rearrangement of the input data counts towards the total computation time. The vectors will not be re-used in the alternate arrangement so it's basically a waste of time.
- If it makes things easier for you to assume alignment, or lack of alignment, that's fine, just say so.
- Computing with the bar_i functions allows more flexibility with the access patters, but creates additional challenges w.r.t. the caching of v_out values.

Answer (score 2):

> The data from one input vector clearing out cached data for another
>   vector.

If you are using v_1[i], v_2[i], ..., v_k[i] in the same function call, the input vectors will not clear out data cached for other vectors. For each element you read in a vector, **the CPU will fetch just a cache line, not the entire vector**. So if you read k elements, you will bring k cache lines from each vector.

> Input vector data clearing out cached output vector data.

You have the same case as the above. That won't be the case.

> Output vector data remaining in registers or L1 cache for as long as
>   we need it (in the bar case).

You could try to use **_mm_prefetch** intrinsics to fetch the data before writing it.

> Under-utilization of memory bandwidth.

To do that you need to maximize the number of **full width transactions**. Basically you need that when the CPU fetches a cache line, all the elements are used right away. To do this you must rearrange your data. I would consider all the k vectors as a matrix of k x n elements, **stored in a column major format**.

```
type* pMat = (type*)aligned_alloc(CACHE_LINE_SIZE, n * k * sizeof(type));
v_0[i] = pMat[i * k + 0];
v_1[i] = pMat[i * k + 1];
// ...
v_k-1[i] = pMat[i * k + k-1];
```

That will put the v_0, ... v_k elements in SIMD registers and you might have the chance of better vectorization.

> core idle time, to the extent possible.

Less cache misses, less transcedental instructions will lead to less idle time.

> Write-read-write-read-write sequences on v_out (which might be very
>   expensive if those writes need to be updated into main memory; the
>   motivation here is that it might be tempting to read just one vector,
>   update the output and repeat).

You could decrease the price of the sequences using prefetching (_mm_prefetch).

Comment: But what if, say, v_1[i] and v_2[i] reside in the same cache line? Won't that mean that whenever I read v_1[i] I lose v_2[i] (and v_2[i+1]), and whenever I read v_2[i] I lose v_1[i] (and v_1[i+1])?

Comment: See my edit regarding what I want to avoid w.r.t. output (and intermediary output) data being cleared from the cache. Is prefetch really relevant? The point is I don't want it to go to main memory at all, just stay in cache in place of other things which might replace it, so I could continue work on further bar's or on the i+1 output.

Comment: Finally, data rearrangement is not an option, unfortunately - see my notes.

Comment: @einpoklum v_1[i] and v_2[i] cannot stay on the same cache line unless you have rearranged the data as I suggested. W.r.t to prefetching, that can be used to avoid cache line eviction of your intermediary output. Doing that, you let the CPU know that that data must not be cleared.

Comment: Did you profile your program with perf or any other profiler to see how much cache misses you have?

Comment: No, it's a bit tricky, because it's sort of a graft onto a larger app and things get spawned etc. But I need to isolate this and profile I guess.

Answer (score 1):

To reduce the clearing out of cached data, you could rearrange your `k` vectors to `1` vector holding a structure with `k` members. That way, the loop will access those elments in sequence and not jump around in memory.

```
struct VectorData
{
    Type1 Var1;
    Type2 Var2;
    // ...
    TypeK VarK;
};

std::vector<VectorData> v_in;

for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
    v_out[i] = foo(v_in[i].Var1, v_in[i].Var2, ... , v_in[i].VarK);
    // Or just pass the whole element:
    v_out[i] = foo(v_in[i]);
}
```

Comment: This means using k*n extra space and taking the time to read and write k*n elements - and this all counts towards my computation (have just edited to emphasize this point). Are you sure that's useful?

Comment: @einpoklum I did not know that you cannot rearrange your input data without cost. You should profile your code to find out if it helps or not. But you are right, it will probably be worse in that case.

Comment: Given that SIMD woks on SOA, converting to AOS is *probably* a terrible idea.